# I am trying to make an application that tracks multiple users

Tags: gps, tracking

I am trying to make a application that tracks multiple people on Google maps and allows the user to see who he wants to track.

I would like this app to send the long and lat to mysql. I am having trouble trying to get the longitude and latitude of the user to update in mysql. What is the best way to to do this?

All i want to do is track multiple people and plot them on a user map, so if the user wanted to see where his friends where at it would show on his cell phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web, you can get each users location from the browser using geolocation:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Since you don't say what your app is written in though we cannot offer any more specific advice.

You will then need to upload that to your app and store it in the database along with a key identifying each user.

The client would then have to be able to pick which of these users they wish to view, at which point you would draw them on a map using something like Google Maps API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/

Comment: I would like to send my longitude and latitude to MySQL database so that i can plot more users on my map can you please direct me to what is the best way to do this thank you.I provided you with the code i am currently using...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!-- 
    geoLocMap.html by Bill Weinman 
    <http://bw.org/contact/>
    created 2011-07-07
    updated 2011-07-20

    Copyright (c) 2011 The BearHeart Group, LLC
    This file may be used for personal educational purposes as needed. 
    Use for other purposes is granted provided that this notice is
    retained and any changes made are clearly indicated as such. 
-->

<head>
    <title>
        Geolocation Map Test (1.1.3)
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
        #map_canvas { height: 100%; width: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var watchID;
        var geo;    // for the geolocation object
        var map;    // for the google map object
        var mapMarker;  // the google map marker object

        // position options
        var MAXIMUM_AGE = 200; // miliseconds
        var TIMEOUT = 300000;
        var HIGHACCURACY = true;

        function getGeoLocation() {
            try {
                if( !! navigator.geolocation ) return navigator.geolocation;
                else return undefined;
            } catch(e) {
                return undefined;
            }
        }

        function show_map(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lon = position.coords.longitude;
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

            if(map) {
                map.panTo(latlng);
                mapMarker.setPosition(latlng);
            } else {
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 18,
                    center: latlng,

                    // mapTypeID --
                    // ROADMAP displays the default road map view
                    // SATELLITE displays Google Earth satellite images
                    // HYBRID displays a mixture of normal and satellite views
                    // TERRAIN displays a physical map based on terrain information.
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                map.setTilt(0); // turns off the annoying default 45-deg view

                mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    title:"You are here."
                });
                mapMarker.setMap(map);
            }
        }

        function geo_error(error) {
            stopWatching();
            switch(error.code) {
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    alert('Geolocation Timeout');
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    alert('Geolocation Position unavailable');
                    break;
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    alert('Geolocation Permission denied');
                    break;
                default:
                    alert('Geolocation returned an unknown error code: ' + error.code);
            }
        }

        function stopWatching() {
            if(watchID) geo.clearWatch(watchID);
            watchID = null;
        }

        function startWatching() {
            watchID = geo.watchPosition(show_map, geo_error, {
                enableHighAccuracy: HIGHACCURACY,
                maximumAge: MAXIMUM_AGE,
                timeout: TIMEOUT
            });
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            if((geo = getGeoLocation())) {
                startWatching();
            } else {
                alert('Geolocation`enter code here` not supported.')
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```